# highcharts override addEvent function

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

in [highcharts javascript file](http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js) line number 1126 there is a function **addEvent**

```
/**
         * Add an event listener
         * @param {Object} el A HTML element or custom object
         * @param {String} event The event type
         * @param {Function} fn The event handler
         */
        addEvent: function (el, event, fn) {
            $(el).bind(event, fn);
        },
```

I want to call my custom function instead of default function, and at the same time i don't want to change highcharts.js.

I want to assign it through external function, is there any way I can achieve this??

**my new code will be**

```
addEvent: function (el, event, fn) {
    if(typeof(fn)=="string"){
        try {
            eval(fn); 
        } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
        }

    }
    $(el).bind(event, fn);
}
```

Comment: Have you solved it in the end?

Comment: not yet.. for now now I made changes in highcharts source code..

Comment: From what I can tell, you would need to specify your own custom HighchartsAdapter since that is were `addEvent()` is defined.  `addEvent()` can't be wrapped using the `wrap()` function provided.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuantely I don't know why wrapping addEvent doesn't work (while should!), but you can overwrite or wrap importEvents for point, to do similar thing (but only for points):

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'importEvents', function () {
        if (!this.hasImportedEvents) {
            var point = this,
                options = H.merge(point.series.options.point, point.options),
                events = options.events,
                eventType;

            point.events = events;

            for (eventType in events) {
                if (typeof events[eventType] == "string") {
                    try {
                        events[eventType] = eval(events[eventType]);
                    } catch (e) {
                        if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
                            console.log(e.message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                H.addEvent(point, eventType, events[eventType]);
                this.hasImportedEvents = true;
            }
        }
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cXS5u/

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite this function by [wrap](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts) function.

Comment: yesterday I tried almost each and every possibility.. but nothing works :(

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
Highcharts.addEvent = (function(orig) {
  return function(el, event, fn) {
    if(typeof fn == "string") {
        try {
            eval(fn); 
        } catch (e) {
          if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
            console.log(e.message);
          }
        }
    }

    orig(el, event, fn);
  };
})(Highcharts.addEvent);
```

using Highcharts' `wrap` method, this should be

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H, "addEvent", function(addEvent, el, event, fn) {
    if(typeof fn == "string") {
      try {
        eval(fn); 
      } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
          console.log(e.message);
        }
      }
    }

    addEvent(el, event, fn);
  });
})(Highcharts);
```

Comment: have a look at demo .. its not working .. on point click event I am sending a function string...    http://jsfiddle.net/5btfM/

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to reproduce the effect of modifying the source code for `addEvent` at line 1126 by using the wrap utility, because for reasons I don't fully understand, the wrap is not applied to numerous internal calls made to `addEvent` including those triggered as a result of the events specified in the initial configuration, such as yours under plotOptions/series/point/events.

However the wrap is applied to events when added like this:

```
(function (H) {
    Highcharts.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push(function (chart) {
        H.addEvent(chart.container, 'click', function() { alert('click!') });
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

or as in your case, adding a function as a string to a point event:

```
(function (H) {
    Highcharts.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push(function (chart) {    
        H.addEvent(chart.series[0].data, 'click', "(function() { alert (this.y);})");
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

so your wrap function could deal with both of these like so:

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H, "addEvent", function (addEvent, el, event, fn) {
        if (typeof fn == "string") {
            try {
                var evalfn = eval(fn);
                addEvent(el, event, evalfn);
            } catch (e) {
                if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            }
        } else {
            addEvent(el, event, fn);
        }
    });
})(Highcharts);
```

which I grant is not quite what you asked, but may offer an alternative solution for what you are trying to achieve.

Demo of all this here: http://jsfiddle.net/8wRAs/

Comment: if I know in advance that which series to click and where events are binded then best solution for me is to use eval in chart object like {series:{events:{click:eval('(function(){alert(this.y)})')}}} .. I am getting series object in JSON format of a AJAX response .. and there I have to recursively iterate the object and and check for "events" tag and then use eval() for all child elements .. if I am using above solution my problem will be same like recursively iterate the JSON object and apply click events to it.. I want to avoid those recursive iteration

Comment: I see! In that case I'm afraid I believe (but stand to be corrected if anyone can gracefully override that function) that you are stuck with having to either recurse the JSON or edit the HighCharts.js source as you have done. Personally I'd go for the former every time. It's only a few lines of code and is drop in the ocean of processing compared to what HighCharts is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying `Highcharts.addEvent` with `Highcharts.wrap()` doesn't work because Highcharts [saves an internal reference](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/v3.0.9/js/highcharts.src.js#L1280) to `addEvent`. Changing the external `Highcharts.addEvent` has no effect on the internal reference.

---

Tracing the code backwards a bit, you'll find that `addEvent` [comes from `window.HighchartsAdapter`](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/v3.0.9/js/highcharts.src.js#L910). Highcharts can be made to work with other JavaScript frameworks by [loading the appropriate adapter](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation), which overrides the default `window.HighchartsAdapter` with a version that works with the particular framework.

To modify `addEvent` on the default adapter before Highcharts saves an internal reference, we can load the main JS file twice: ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/E7T7H/))

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script>
    // Highcharts detects if it has been loaded more than once
    // and throws an error to alert developers
    // We work around this by unsetting the Highcharts object
    window.Highcharts = null;

    window.HighchartsAdapter.addEvent = function (el, event, fn) {
        // add your custom code here

        $(el).bind(event, fn);
    };
</script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

This will cause a second HTTP request to be made for the JS file, but it should return a 304 response as the browser should already have cached the file from the first request.

---

While this may work for now, monkey-patching someone else's code isn't the best way to proceed in the long term, e.g. you or another developer may decide to upgrade to the latest version of Highcharts (with a completely different internal API) a year from now, without realizing / remembering this change. I'd consider other ways to do what you're trying to do before resorting to monkey patching.

Comment: @AnupSingh were you able to try this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Notice these lines of code in highcharts.js:

```
// check for a custom HighchartsAdapter defined prior to this file
var globalAdapter = win.HighchartsAdapter,
    adapter = globalAdapter || {};

// Initialize the adapter
if (globalAdapter) {
    globalAdapter.init.call(globalAdapter, pathAnim);
}


// Utility functions. If the HighchartsAdapter is not defined, adapter is an empty object
// and all the utility functions will be null. In that case they are populated by the
// default adapters below.
```

Since `addEvent` is specified in `window.HighchartsAdapter`, you will need to create a custom `HighchartsAdapter` to override it. There is an example of a custom highcharts adapter on [github](https://gist.github.com/anutron/2129031).

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM events easily in a way compatible with all browsers. Here is the experience ...

Create your function, for example mouseup ...

```
var MeObjectDOM_mouseup = function(){
           Me blabla code....
}
```

Create your event now ...

```
if(MeObjectDOM.addEventListener){
 MeObjectDOM.addEventListener("mouseup", MeObjectDOM_mouseup ,true);
}else if(MeObjectDOM.attachEvent){
MeObjectDOM.attachEvent("mouseup", MeObjectDOM_mouseup);
}else{
 MeObjectDOM['onmouseup'] = MeObjectDOM_mouseup;
};
```

Your event is now compatible with IE, NETSCAPE, CHROME, EDGE, OPERA, FIREFOX, SAFARI, even older versions like Safari 5 or IE 5, 6 and Netscape 4 (^__^).

- Chrome Mozilla it was Netscape before the recovery by Google. FireFox, and OPERA come from MOZILLA except IE and SAFARI. So your code will be compatible with all existing browsers since 1980 and before until 2019 see much more ....